# How to initialize test class resources in Visual Studio Unit Testing framework?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm using the unit testing framework in .NET in C++/CLI to test unmanaged C++ code.

I would like for example an instance of `System::Random` to generate random values throughout the test methods.

Do I need to put this as a member variable in my test class?

If yes where can I put the initialization code, cause the `ClassInitialize()` method that is generated is static for some reason and it only has access to a `TestContext` which I read is only for using testing data from some external sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add static properties to your test class and initialize them in the `ClassInitialize()` method if you need them to be available to all tests.  If you want them initialized per test, then using the `TestInitialize()` method is better.

Are you sure you want to use random values in your unit tests?  Typically you'd want to use known values (good values, bad values, edge cases, etc) so that your tests are predictable.  Using multiple tests with various values where you know the expected behavior (outcome) is more typical than using random values.

Comment: Right static members, I haven't taught of that. In that case which is better, static member initialized in `ClassInitialize` or non-static member initialized in the regular constructor for example.

About the second part, yeah I agree. I'm pretty much beginner at writing unit tests, and basically the method I'm testing should work with any integer, that's why I taught maybe use a random one since it doesn't matter.

Comment: @sekme64 - I'd use either the ClassInitialize or TestInitialize over using the constructor; which would depend on whether what is being set up needs to be reset before each test or not.